# "CMultiFileUpload" only saves the last files info in db from the mutiliple files in YII?

Tags: php, database, file-upload, yii, insert

I am using "CMultiFileUpload" to upload multiple files in YII. I am using the following code:

```
public function actionAddProductImages($id)
{       
    $model=new ProductImages;
    if(isset($_POST['ProductImages']))
    {   
                $model->attributes=$_POST['ProductImages'];
                $files = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image');                                                            
                foreach ($files as $file)
                {
                        //$rnd = rand(0,9999);                                                                                  
                        $fileName = $file->getName();                                                   
                        $model->image = $fileName;
                        $model->product_id = $id;
                        $model->sortorder = $_POST['ProductImages']['sortorder'];                       
                        if($model->save())
                        {                                   
                            //$files->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName); // image will uplode to rootDirectory/banner/   
                            $file->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName);
                             //thumbmail---------------start---
                            Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/productImage/original/');                
                            Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName)->resize(538,359)->save($fileName);

                            Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/productImage/thumb/');               
                            Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName)->resize('0','110')->save($fileName);  

                            Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/productImage/thumb_70/');
                            Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName)->resize('0',70)->save($fileName); 
                        }
                }

                    /*Yii::app()->user->setFlash('productImage','productImage has been added successfully');
                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->image_id));*/

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

**Actually what happens with this code:** it saves only the last file's information in databases and uploads all the selected files in the specified folder. please help me to find where i am being wrong.
I am new to YII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try (new image - new row in db, that why new model):

> ```
> public function actionAddProductImages($id)
> {
>     if(isset($_POST['ProductImages']))
>     {
>         $files = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image');
>         foreach ($files as $file)
>         {
>             $model=new ProductImages;
>             $model->attributes=$_POST['ProductImages'];
>             //$rnd = rand(0,9999);                                                                                  
>             $fileName = $file->getName();
>             $model->image = $fileName;
>             $model->product_id = $id;
>             $model->sortorder = $_POST['ProductImages']['sortorder'];
>             if($model->save())
>             {
>                 //$files->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName); // image will uplode to rootDirectory/banner/   
>                 $file->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName);
>                 //thumbmail---------------start---
>                 Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/productImage/original/');
>                 Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName)->resize(538,359)->save($fileName);
>                 Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/productImage/thumb/');
>                 Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName)->resize('0','110')->save($fileName);
>                 Yii::app()->thumb->setThumbsDirectory('/upload/productImage/thumb_70/');
>                 Yii::app()->thumb->load(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/productImage/'.$fileName)->resize('0',70)->save($fileName);
>             }
>         }
>         /*Yii::app()->user->setFlash('productImage','productImage has been added successfully');
>         $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->image_id));*/
>     }
>     $this->render('create',array(
>         'model'=>$model,
>     ));
> }
> ```